# A page manipulation scripting in browser

Tags: javascript, browser, scroll

Let's say I need to scroll a very long list of tweets on twitter. As you may know, twitter loads older tweets asynchronously, whenever the web page has been scrolled to the bottom. It retrieves the older set of tweets and re-sizes the page's height. And you scroll again.

I assume I can just have a java script that can scroll all the way down to February tweets, for example.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to write such a script?
2. Where would I be able to inject it, in case I am not controlling the page serving from the server and can't add the script to the page's content?

Comment: If you don't control the page content and it's not coming from your own domain, you can't do this with client-side JavaScript at all, really. If the site has some sort of API that would let you fetch raw data and format it yourself, then you could do it. Or, alternatively, you could do all the work from your own server, screen-scraping content and then showing it via your own user interface.

Comment: I am positive I've seen examples of injection of custom java script right into the address bar. This is why I asked. Thanks for an answer anyway.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to do this on your PC only? then you can use greasemonkey...

Comment: Oh yes, if you're talking about just doing it for your own benefit and not as part of a web site, then you can use something like Greasemonkey as @nyarlathotep says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to add additional javascript to a page you're viewing in your browser; am I correct?

If so, and you're using Firefox browser, try [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/). There are solutions for other browsers as well; e.g. Chrome [supports such user scripts](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24790/beginner-guide-for-greasemonkey-scripts-in-google-chrome/) out of the box...

Out in the web you'll also find thousands of userscripts for various purposes (e.g. at [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/)), maybe there is already one doing exactly what you need (or near enough so that it's easily adaptable).

Comment: Yep, this is what I've been inquiring about. Thank you.